# Replicate dplyr::left_join() column order with data.table x[y] syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am switching a lot of my data manipulation pipelines from dplyr to data.table because of improved performance. I like the conciseness of the `a[b]` syntax for joins. `dplyr::left_join(x, y)` corresponds to `y[x]` in `data.table`. However the column order is different in both cases. Is there a  way to  replicate the column order you get from a dplyr `left_join` where new columns from `y` are added to the right-hand side of `x`, using the `y[x]` syntax of data.table? I know you can use `merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE)` but I was curious if the `[]` way can achieve the same result.

### example

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

x <- iris
y <- data.frame(Species = c('setosa', 'virginica'), foo = c(100, 200))

j1 <- left_join(x, y)

setDT(x)
setDT(y)

j2 <- y[x, on = 'Species']

j3 <- merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE)
```

How do I make `j2` have the same column order as `j1` and `j3`?

```
> head(j1, 1)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species foo
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 100
> head(j2, 1)
   Species foo Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1:  setosa 100          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
> head(j3, 1)
   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width foo
1:  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an assignment (`:=`), which would be more efficient as this does by reference

```
j2 <- copy(x)
j2[y, foo := foo, on = .(Species)]
```

-testing

```
all.equal(j1, type.convert(as.data.frame(j2), as.is = TRUE))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: If there are multiple columns in `y` other than the column we are joining on, wouldn't this require you to assign all of them with `:=`?

Comment: @qdread If there are more e.g. foo1, foo2, etc. `nm1 <- names(y)[3:5]` , then `j2[y, (nm1) := mget(nm1), on = .(Species)]`

Comment: Or if it is all the columns except 'Species', `nm1 <- setdiff(names(y), 'Species')` and then apply the same code

Comment: This is a nice answer but in the end I think the code ends up being more verbose than the `merge()` way so I may just stick with that!

Comment: @qdread I would say the `:=` should be faster